# Manage memory in mobile apps that have infinite scrolling with images and real-time interaction

Tags: android, ios, mobile, memory-management, real-time

I'm designing a mobile app which will contain a list of images and videos which will be loaded from a server, this list will be very big and the user will scroll through many pages.

I'm afraid that loading all these images and videos might cause memory leaks and the app might crash due to low memory.

So how should I manage the memory for such an app? what is the best practice to manage the memory of images and have a very smooth scrolling experience without having any memory warnings on both iOS and Android? What techniques should I use in my app (images caching for example)

Also, the app will have real-time interactions, each time a user add an image or a video the data will be refreshed. And I need to have a scalable app that could eventually have millions of users.

I already searched and found PubNub and Google's FireBase that could really help in implementing such an experience, but do you have any other suggestions?

I need to know about best practices for such an app, I already searched a lot and couldn't find a complete answer.

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I always use [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher). its the best for image caching. See also TableView and collection view prefetching delegate functions

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, Actually I'm already using KingFisher and I'm familiar with all its features, but I was looking for much more detailed answer, for example, what is the best way to use KingFisher in case the user scrolled for over 1000+ image without affecting both memory and performance (scrolling smoothly), especially that KingFisher has memory cache and that could drop the free memory very badly.

Comment: At my company we use IGListKit. Which helps memory management by only keeping a range of the items in memory. You could look at that.